Power series with coefficients constructed by termwise multiplying Taylor coefficients of two functions
For the Taylor series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$$
we define the series
$$h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_nx^n.$$
Is there a relation between $h$ and the functions $f$ and $g$ that can be written explicitly in the form $h(x)=$"some expression involving $f$ and $g$"?

Note that $h$ is called the Hadamard product of $f$ and $g$. Some posts on this site may already have what you are searching for.
